# React Native (Redux) FlatList jumping to top of list when onEndReached called

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList in ReactNative which pulls a list of articles from an API. When the end of the list is reached on scrolling, a further page of articles is pulled from the API and appended to the articles list in a Redux reducer.

The FlatList is set up as:

```
render() {
    return(
    <FlatList data={this.props.articles.articles} // The initial articles list via Redux state
        renderItem={this.renderArticleListItem} // Just renders the list item.
        onEndReached={this.pageArticles.bind(this)} // Simply calls a Redux Action Creator/API
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}/>
   )};
```

The Redux 'articles' state object is mapped to the component using the React Redux connect function.  The relevant reducer (some items removed for brevity) looks like:

```
/// Initial 'articles' state object
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    articles: [],
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 10
};

export default(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    // The relevant part for returning articles from the API
    case ARTICLES_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loading: false, articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload.items), 
            pageIndex: action.payload.pageIndex, pageSize: action.payload.pageSize}
   default:
       return state;
   }
}
```

The payload is a simple object - the articles are contained in the `action.payload.items` array, and there is additional paging information as well in the payload (not important to this problem).

Everything is fine with the API returning the correct data.

The problem is that when the end of the FlatList is reached on scrolling, the API is called, the new articles are pulled fine and appended to the this.props.articles state object and to the FlatList, BUT the FlatList jumps/scrolls back to the first item in the list.

I think the problem is probably with how I am returning the state in the Redux reducer but I'm not sure why.

Is using `concat` the correct way to return the new state with the new articles appended?

Comment: how are you concatenating the data,more detail would be much more helpful, also onEndReached would be called multiple times, what are you doing to reduce that?

Comment: `onEndReachedThreshold={0}` seems invalid code, no ?

Comment: It's concatenated in the reducer during the ARTICLES_SUCCESS case.  onEndReachedThreshold={0} is fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: try this way { ...state, loading: false, articles: [...state.articles , ...action.payload.items]

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: any solution os far ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late to answer this but I experienced exact same problem having my data served from redux to the component and managed to fix the jumping effect by making my component a normal `Component` rather than `PureComponent` allowing me to use `shouldComponentUpdate` life-cycle hook method. This how the method should look like for you component:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
   if (this.props.articles === nextProps.articles) {
       return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

This method (if implemented) should return a boolean value indicating whether the component should update or not. What i did here was to prevent the component from re-rendering in case the contents of `articles` hasn't changed.

Hope this would be helpful for you or others who might have faced similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to listItem styles height and width. Freezing and jumping maybe because list tried to calculate sizes for all items even if they dont display.

And you can find answer in: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13727

Answer (score 0):

Using FlatList as component and adding data as props re-renders whole content, so it scrolls to top. I recommend using it directly inside your page and changing its data using `this.state`, not `props`

Comment: gives same result