# React Native FlatList jumps to the top when adding new items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-apollo, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to add an Infinite Scroll feature to a FlatList:

```
<FlatList
   data={pickupsGroups}
   renderItem={({item , index}: {item: PickupGroup, index: number}) => {
                    return <PickingCard group={item} onPress={onPressPickup}/>
   }}
   onRefresh={onRefresh}
   keyExtractor={item => `${item?.title}-${item?.totalSku}`}
   refreshing={refreshing}
   onEndReached={() => {
     setPage(page + 1)
   }}
   onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
/>
```

when the `page` changes, I run a GraphQL query:

```
    const {loading} = useQuery(MY_GROUPS, {
        variables: {limit: 10, page},
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        onCompleted: data => {
            setPickupsGroups(pickupsGroups.concat(data.myPickupGroups.pickupGroups))
        }
    })
```

But every time I add new items to `pickupGroups`, the FlatList scrolls back to the top

Comment: have a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646021/react-native-redux-flatlist-jumping-to-top-of-list-when-onendreached-called

Comment: I did (also tried a few stuff from it), but it doesn't seem to have a solid answer...

Comment: @EduardoPedroso Could you post a reproducible example on expo snack?

Comment: Can you add `setPickupsGroups` method code

Comment: @MahdiN is just a React hook.

Comment: have you tried adding [extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) prop?

Comment: @MaxGram yes, I did...

Comment: did you check if all the <PickingCards> get an key prop? add an console.log(index) to the renderItem method. If the pagination is working correctly it should could up, if its start at zero at every refresh there are often problems with the keys of the list

Comment: - Did you give styles height and width to your PickingCard component to avoir Flatlist to recalculate sizes for all items (every PickingCard component) ?
- Is your keyExtractor Flatlist props return a unique key that doesn't change for each items (previous or new)  when the data list change ?

Comment: Hello, you can control this issue, take flatList ref and stored last scroll stop point value after updated your state/component use with ref.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index /lastPointValue}) , thanks   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you call method setPickupsGroups in onCompleted Method, it causes screen to re-render, try using a global variable for pickUpGroups, or if you are using apollo graphQL, then from your graphQL server try sending hasMore, and in app side call fetchMore Update Query which will not cause your screen to re-render and it won't scroll to top..